# Java check a specific condition after a thread terminates

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following code

```
    PlayerMove move;
    Thread t = new Thread(new Timer());
    t.start();
    move = this.currentPlayer.GetPlayerMove();
```

how I can check if the move variable is null after the thread t terminates?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking for. Do you want to know how to check if the thread ended? Do you want to know how to write a loop and wait for that method to return a null result?

Comment: if `currentPlayer.GetPlayerMove()` doesn't return `null` until after the thread ended then `move` might never be null unless the thread executes so fast that it will end right before `GetPlayerMove()` is called. Besides that, you'd need to know when the thread has finished and there are a number of ways to do that (e.g. use a `Future`, join the threads etc.) - what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @GhostCat I want to know if the move var is null or not after the timer thread ends.

Comment: Are you maybe trying to give the player the opportunity to move for a given time?

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for your response . What i want to achieve is giving a player a limited time to make a move and if he/she doesn't i wanna stop the game.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is what you want is something like this:

```
CompletableFuture<PlayerMove> moveFuture = supplyAsync(currentPlayer::getPlayerMove);

try {
    PlayerMove move = moveFuture.get(limit, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    // player moved
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    // player did not move
}
```

[CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) is an interface representing a result that gets calculated in a separate thread (in this case, a call to currentPlayer.getPlayerMove()). You can retrieve the result by calling `get()` which will wait forever or (as in this case), for a specified period of time. If that timeout has elapsed, a `TimeoutException` is thrown.

Comment: Can you explain this solution please?

Comment: @E.Omar Added an explanation to the answer.